# python improving list handling for a bigger input

Tags: python, performance

The idea of my code is that when there is a duplication of the same user with the same device_id, it will update the list (in my case, creating a new list) and remove duplicate entries. 
Also it will take the last id1, id2, and id3 from the duplicate entry and put them together in one entry in the new list as well as updating the type with type of the duplication.

To explain this, I provide an example with 4 lists (printed before update and after update the list)

My code works, however I have another lists with around 800k lists, where I tried to run the code and it run for an hour. How can I approach this issue better? (can't change the input type , as this is from another API call, I can only change my code of removing the duplication)

```
my_list = []
#   [device_id, location, type, name, ph, addr, email, id1, id2, id3]
val1=  ['12345653', 'SOUTH', 'Broadband', 'Mr Glasses', '+123344', 'MY ADDRESS', '880@myemail', '', '']
val2=  ['12345653', 'SOUTH', 'IPTV', 'Mr Glasses', '+123344', 'MY ADDRES', '', '999@myemail', '']
val3=  ['98102344', 'SOUTH', 'Voice', 'Ms Chair', '+99123123', 'Corner Street Behind Door', '', '', '990@securemail']
val4=  ['11023424', 'SOUTH', 'IPTV', 'Mr Tree', '+125324', 'Upwards error 123', '', '47@securemail', '']


my_list.append(val1)
my_list.append(val2)
my_list.append(val3)
my_list.append(val4)

for x in my_list:
    print x

print 'start removing duplication'
print ''
def rm_dupl(my_list):
    fin_list = []
    dev_exist = []

    for x in my_list:
        dev_id = x[0]
        if dev_id in dev_exist:
            # if entry exist, we just update the existing entry with 
            # the value of this current x, and not creating a new entry
            for y in fin_list:
                if dev_id in y[0]:
                    # y is retrieved value
                    # below we update with the duplication one
                    if 'Broadband' in x[2]:
                        y[2] += '_Broadband'
                        y[6] = x[6]
                    elif 'IPTV' in x[2]:
                        y[2] += '_IPTV'
                        y[7] = x[7]
                    elif 'Voice' in x[2]:
                        y[2] += '_Voice'
                        y[8] = x[8]
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            fin_list.append(x)
            dev_exist.append(dev_id)
    return fin_list


updated_list = rm_dupl(my_list)
for x in updated_list:
    print x
```

Comment: If you don't care about the order, look at using sets? They are much faster than lists in some cases.

Comment: @KuboMD was my first reaction too but in this case the solution is a plain dict (or an OrderedDict if order matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already mentionned, scanning a list is not only quite inefficient but also O(n) so the bigger your list the worse the lookup time.

Here you have two list scans, one implicit (`dev_id in dev_exist`) and one explicit (`for y in fin_list: if dev_id in y[0]:`).

The solution is to use a dict (or a `collections.OrderedDict` if insertion order matters) to store the deduplicated result, with the "id" as key and the row as value - Dict key lookups are 0(1) (constant time) and very quick. This dict will also replace the `dev_exist` list.

Also given your example data you probably want to replace the `if 'somestring' in x[i]` with `if x[i] == 'somestring'`, which is more accurate (`'foo' in 'foobar'` will return true, probably not what you want) and (slightly) faster (depending on the string's length).

```
def rm_dupl(my_list):
    results = {} # or `collections.OrderedDict`

    for row in my_list:
        prev_row = results.get(row[0])
        if prev_row:
            # if entry exist, we just update the existing entry with 
            # the value of this current row, and not creating a new entry
            # below we update with the duplication one

            val = row[2] # avoids multiple access to `row[2]`
            if val == 'Broadband':
                prev_row[2] += '_Broadband'
                prev_row[6] = row[6]
            elif val == 'IPTV':
                prev_row[2] += '_IPTV'
                prev_row[7] = row[7]
            elif val == 'Voice':
                prev_row[2] += '_Voice'
                prev_row[8] = row[8]

        else:
            # no matching row found, let's add
            # a new one
            results[dev_id] = row

    # and returns the values
    # NB in py3 you'll want `list(results.values())` instead
    return results.values()
```

Comment: yes, should have used dict O(1) . tried with real data and improved a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `dev_exist` a set, checking whether a value is present becomes much faster.
Currently, each value will have to loop through all the values in the `dev_exist` list to check whether it is already present. However, checking presence of a value in a set is done using hashing and will be much faster.

That'll take care of a significant part of the time.

EDIT:
You can also replace the list by a dict when looking for duplicates. Dicts also provide quick `in` methods.

```
my_dict = {}
for val in my_list:
    if val[0] in my_dict:
        print(val[0], "exists already")
        # Your code for replacing an existing entry here
    else:
        my_dict[val[0]] = val[1:]

# To convert back to a list
new_list = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    new_list.append([key]+value)
```

Comment: I assumed duplicates wouldn't be too common. I suppose we don't actually know that. I added a dictionary approach that should solve it.